# Page setup during print preview in Crystal Reports for VS 2010

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

Is it possible to see the page setup during print preview of crystal reports during run time?

Because there are times that we need to set the top and bottom margin of the report.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the report margins, but I have seen something to control the Size in % of the report. You set the %size of the report before you print the rpt.